# How generate multilevel Viber keyboard

Tags: python, viber, viber-api, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

I'm trying to build keyboard for Viber bot using [viber-bot-python](https://github.com/Viber/viber-bot-python) and following code:

```py
keyboard = {
    "DefaultHeight": True,
    "BgColor": self.background_color,
    "Type": "keyboard",
    "Buttons": [
        {
            "Columns": 2,
            "Rows": 3,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '1',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '1'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 2,
            "Rows": 3,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '2',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '2'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 2,
            "Rows": 3,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '3',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '3'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 2,
            "Rows": 3,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '4',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '4'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 1,
            "Rows": 3,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '5',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '5'
        }
    ]
}
```

And expect that will get following structure:

```
Select button:
[1] [2]
[3] [4]
[  5  ]
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```sh
File "\venv\lib\site-packages\viberbot\api\message_sender.py", line 53, in _post_request
    raise Exception(u"failed with status: {0}, message: {1}".format(result['status'], result['status_message']))
Exception: failed with status: 3, message: keyboard is not valid. [numeric instance is greater than the required maximum (maximum: 2, found: 3)]
```

I've read topic about [keyboard design](https://viber.github.io/docs/tools/keyboards/#keyboard-design), but it doesn't help.
What is wrong with it and how to correctly build the keyboard for Viber Bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you misunderstood image in [keyboard-design](https://viber.github.io/docs/tools/keyboards/#keyboard-design) topic. It means that a single button can fit place in that grid (6x2).

[image: keyboard-design]

So if you need to build menu like:

```
Select button:
[1] [2]
[3] [4]
[  5  ]
```

Then for each button you need to set how much place each button should take.
First 4 buttons - will take **3 (of 6)** columns, and the last 5th - **6 (of 6)**.
And each button can take **1 row** (if you want small button) or **2 rows** (if you want them big). Button with 3 rows is not possible.

And now your code should look like following:

```py
keyboard = {
    "DefaultHeight": True,
    "BgColor": self.background_color,
    "Type": "keyboard",
    "Buttons": [
        {
            "Columns": 3,
            "Rows": 1,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '1',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '1'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 3,
            "Rows": 1,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '2',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '2'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 3,
            "Rows": 1,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '3',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '3'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 3,
            "Rows": 1,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '4',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '4'
        },
        {
            "Columns": 6,
            "Rows": 1,
            "BgColor": "#e6f5ff",
            "ActionType": 'reply',
            "ActionBody": '5',
            "ReplyType": "message",
            "Text": '5'
        }
    ]
}
```